# Swaping bakgrounds of a layout wihtout moving the foreground image in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewgroup, fragmentpageradapter

I have a question,

is it possible to swap between a no. of backgrounds by swiping on screen and at same time  to keep an image always on top of the background irrelevant of the background changes.

backgrounds could be stored in an array and call it in program , and i tried ViewPager already and it is not much effective as the image moves along with the background.

Maybe applying fade-in transition effect on view pager could solve it, is there any method to do that in a ViewPager ?

Here is the code which i used in pager adapter:

```
private class MainAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        ImageView img =new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.car);
        int bg = Color.rgb((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64, 
                (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64,
                (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*128)+64);
        img.setBackgroundColor(bg);
        container.addView(img, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mViewPager.setObjectForPosition(img, position);
        return img;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object obj) {
        container.removeView(mViewPager.findViewFromObject(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        if (view instanceof OutlineContainer) {
            return ((OutlineContainer) view).getChildAt(0) == obj;
        } 
            else 
        {
            return view == obj;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: i just got a hint, using motionEvent in the onTouch method is the key, assign two overlays and a gradient container and use them in a relative layout applied through code, put some backgrounds (say colours ) in an array and call them on overlays by incrementing the value each time the swipe activity occurs. but i am not that experienced to implement this idea into code, any big head is there to help ? it'll be helpful for others too.